# Change IsPostBack during debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, postback, webforms

I know it isn't possible to change IsPostBack in code:

```
IsPostBack = false;
```

because it has not setter. But can I change it during debug? I tried, but couldn't. So, it isn't possible?

Comment: Are you trying to disable it completely? Or is there a particular event that you do not want it to initiate a postback?

Comment: I just want to check something. When I press button and get postback, some controls change their position and look. So I think that if IsPostBack = true, then some css or jquery are not loading correctly. Just want to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advantage the debugger provides is that it allows you to modify a backing field if there is no setter or call the setter if it's inaccessible.  In this case there is no setter nor is there a backing field.  The `Page.IsPostBack` property is a calculated property and done so on several values which are hard to modify.

You could try to modify some of the expressions that factors into the calculation of `IsPostBack`.  For example if the field `_isCrossPagePostBack` is `true` and `_requestValueCollection` isn't `null` then `IsPostBack` will evaluate to `true`.  But changing both of these would affect more than `IsPostBack` because other property values would also change.  This would work, but would have unintended consequences.  It's not something I would try.

Comment: @Alex yes and no.  you could try and modify one of the expressions used in the calculation of `IsPostBack` like `_isCrossPagePostBack`.  But that would have other effects on the system (likely one you didn't intend)

Comment: okay, _isCrossPagePostBack was false, _requestValueCollection was not null, I changed _requestValueCollection = null and IsPostBack changed to false

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things come to mind that you could do to manage that. 
- Move any logic that you can into

```
(!IsPostBack)
{

}
```

-setup breakpoints where controls are created (if they are dynamic). This way you can tell what is being changed on a postback.

Comment: yes, I know I can check code everywhere where it check IsPostBack, problem that I have several cascading master pages and also page inherited from other class (which inherited too). I just wanted to do a fast check.